# How can I get animation from PPTX by using Apache POI API

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm converting PPT and PPTX file to HTML.

I can get background pictures,text,layout and so on.But I can't get custom shape and animation.

Some code of my project:

```
public static void getPic(XMLSlideShow ppts) throws Exception {

    for (XSLFPictureData data : ppts.getPictureData()) {
        String index = data.getIndex()+1 + "";
        String ext = data.getType().extension;

        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(path + "imgPPTX\\" + index + ext);
        InputStream pIs = data.getInputStream();
        if (ext.equals(".wmf")) {
            Wmf2Svg.convert(path + index + ext);
            ext = ".svg";
        }
        // System.out.println(pict.getHeader().toString());
        img.put(data.getFileName(), index + ext);

        fileout.write(data.getData());
        fileout.close();
        pIs.close();
    }

}

public static void getBg(XSLFSlide ppt) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ppt.getSlideNumber() + ":  " + ppt.getSlideLayout().getTheme().getName() + "   " + ppt.getSlideLayout().getName());
    XSLFBackground bg = ppt.getBackground();
    CTBackground xmlBg = (CTBackground) bg.getXmlObject();
    if (xmlBg.getBgPr().getBlipFill() != null) {
        String relId = xmlBg.getBgPr().getBlipFill().getBlip().getEmbed();

        XSLFPictureData pic = (XSLFPictureData) ppt.getRelationById(relId);
        htmlins.insertImg(img.get(pic.getFileName()), "[x=0,y=0,w="+pageSize.getWidth()+",h="+pageSize.getHeight()+"]");
        // System.out.println("backg: " + pic.getFileName());
    } else {
        // System.out.println("backg: no background");
    }
    for (XSLFShape shape : ppt.getSlideLayout().getShapes()) {
            dealBGShape(shape);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you find solution regarding getting animation ?